# MySQL: UPDATE too slow

Tags: mysql, database

The following is a  benchmark of a series of queries I have to run. As you can see, the UPDATEs are significantly slower than the other queries. **What can I do to speed them up?**

```
0.0002  LOCK TABLE category WRITE; 
0.0004  
        SELECT
            @myLeft := left_id
        FROM
            category
        WHERE
            `amazon_browse_node_id` = 2675;

0.0184  UPDATE category SET right_id = right_id + 2 WHERE right_id > @myLeft; 
0.0161  UPDATE category SET left_id = left_id + 2 WHERE left_id > @myLeft; 
0.0007  INSERT INTO category(`name`, `amazon_browse_node_id`, `category_seo_friendly_url`, `left_id`, `right_id`) VALUES('Training', 2697, 'training-2697/', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2); 
0.0004  UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This problem is related to the following problems (and my attempt at a solution), which I also posted here in SO:

1. [MySQL: nested set is slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025164/mysql-nested-set-is-slow)
2. [MySQL trigger in order to cache results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035097/mysql-trigger-in-order-to-cache-results)

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category`
  (
     `category_id`               INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name`                      CHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `category_seo_friendly_url` CHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `left_id`                   INT(11) DEFAULT '1',
     `right_id`                  INT(11) DEFAULT '2',
     PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `seo_friendly_url_UNIQUE` (`category_seo_friendly_url`),
     KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
     KEY `left_id` (`left_id`),
     KEY `right_id` (`right_id`)
  )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing that could help is proper keys on right_id and left_id. Even then, updates are just slower than selects or inserts. There is not a lot you can do about it.

Comment: what do you mean by proper keys on right_id and left_id? Is my table structure wrong?

Comment: The UPDATEs will benefit from an index on right_id and left_id, respectively. To be useful in this case, you need an index where right_id is the only column or is at least the leftmost column in a composite index. The same for left_id. Then, a range scan can be done on the indexes to find the rows to update.

Comment: For a typical value of @myLeft as produced by the first query, use EXPLAIN to see if an index will be used and how many rows will likely be examined. For example, assuming 672 would be a realistic value -- EXPLAIN UPDATE category SET right_id = right_id + 2 WHERE right_id > 672; If a really large number of rows are being updated, that would explain why the updates are slow.

Comment: @Robert: see my update. Aren't left_id and right_id already indexed?

Comment: Yes, those two columns are correctly indexed. But, you have at least one too many indexes. You should get rid of the secondary index on category_id, since category_id is already the primary key. Run "show indexes from category;" and you will see what I mean. Drop it with "alter table category drop index category_id;". Secondary indexes take up disk space and must be maintained during inserts, updates, deletes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have an index on the table which

1. Speeds up SELECT queries
2. Slows down UPDATE queries since the index needs to be updated

INSERT statements only add one record which means is faster than updating N records.